# Calculo de horas em banco Informix

Tags: informix

Sou iniciante em banco `Informix`, e estou com dificuldade para calcular a diferença entre horas em uma query.

Para o cálculo, os campos `hrinicio` e `hrfim` devem ser usados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Query que tentei:

```
select *,((DATEDIFF(HOUR, hrinicio, hrfim)) % 24) as total_horas from tabela1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando se trata de banco de dados, independente qual banco for sempre informe a versão, isso faz muita diferença pois os BD evoluiram muito e tem muito banco instalado com versões extremamente antigas por ai e consequentemente com menos recursos.

Enfim, este SQL que você escreveu não é válido para o Informix pois não existe a função DATEDIFF nativa nele.
Um bom lugar para tirar duvidas sobre qualquer banco é o seu manual.
Neste caso, você irá encontrar informações sobre calculo de datas neste link : 
 https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_156.htm

Uma informação que está faltando também é o tipo do dado deste campo de hora. Pelo output da sua query, acho pouco provável que seja um DATETIME, provavelmente deve ser um CHAR.
De qualquer maneira o calculo sempre será um tipo INTERVAL e ele é um tipo chato de "converter", para usar seu resultado como numero, sempre é preciso primeiro converte-lo para char.

Veja o exemplo que montei abaixo :

```sql
drop table if exists tp01;
create temp table tp01 (
  hora1 datetime hour to second
 ,hora2 datetime hour to second
 ,hora3 char(8)
 ,hora4 char(8)
)
;

insert into tp01 values ('09:06:55', '14:55:10', '09:06:55','14:55:10');

select * from tp01 ;
select
       hora2 - hora1
     , (hora2 - hora1)::interval hour(2) to hour
     , ((hora2 - hora1)::interval hour(2) to hour)::char(5)
     , hora4::datetime hour to second - hora3::datetime hour to second
from tp01
```

Irá retornar :

```
hora1    hora2    hora3    hora4
09:06:55 14:55:10 09:06:55 14:55:10

(expression) (expression) (expression) (expression)
5:48:15      5            5            5:48:15
```